# PrimeFaces 10 removed method RadioButtonGroup.getSelectItems() replacement

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am updating the project using PrimeFaces from 7 to 10 and I have updated everything but I am having compilation error on `oRadioButtonGroup.getSelectItems()`. The method was removed in PrimeFaces 10. I am looking for a replacement for this method.

```
SelectOneRadio oRadioButtonGroup = (SelectOneRadio) comp;
oComponentState = new JSFComponentState(comp.getId(),
oRadioButtonGroup.getValue(), oRadioButtonGroup.getSelectItems(),
oRadioButtonGroup.isDisabled(), oRadioButtonGroup.isRendered());
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you are looking for is in 'SelectRenderer#getSelectItems', which is protected.
Feel free to create a feature request, to make it accessible in the future again.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/1e3d0dfde48fd7a687610dc0b0c90c7e9be0e688/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/SelectRenderer.java#L65

Comment: Ok, I got what you're saying. But in order to use SelectRenderer#getSelectItems, I'll have to cast my SelectOneRadio object to SelectRenderer object. Can you guide how can I do the same?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I have tried to expose the protected method but it requires arguments getSelectItems(FacesContext context, UIInput component) i have UIInput arg but i do not have FacesContext interface arg can you provide a help on that?

Comment: Looks like a static utility function can also be used for this. Get the context like `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thanks that worked I have another question
Is there an alternate to use SelectOneRadio#setSelectItems() method now from Primefaces 8 or does the SelectRenderer#getSelectItems() already takes care of the same?

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/3142