# Replacement for deprecated selectItems field in SelectOneRadio.java in Primefaces 8

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to upgrade from Primefaces 7 to Primefaces 10 in my project and I realise that `selectItems` field is deprecated and No Longer exists from Primefaces 8 onwards, hence receiving compilation errors in my Project.

Can someone guide me what is the replacement for field `selectItems`
and methods `getSelectItems()` and `setSelectItems()` in SelectOneRadio.java in Primefaces 10 so that I can reuse the functionality related to the same in my Project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PrimeFaces 10 removed method RadioButtonGroup.getSelectItems() replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69640672/primefaces-10-removed-method-radiobuttongroup-getselectitems-replacement)

Comment: I already reviewed that thread but that doesn't answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: While I understand that the method `getSelectItems()` has been moved to SelectRenderer.java, but how does Primefaces handle the variable `selectItems` inside RadioButtonGroup.java

Comment: So in our project we were using `setSelectItems()` for restoring a JSF Page Components by reading a List<SelectItem> from a map which is previously populated using `getSelectItems()`.

I was thinking how can we handle the same now

Comment: @JasperdeVries It seems the code was removed as part of the below commit but can't find an alternative solution for the same https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/6562b5d6ac06c404aefcca76c01f15b91c239b21

Comment: See link in answer in duplicate

Comment: @JasperdeVries Yes I reviewed the answer in duplicate but it doesn't helps unfortunately.
While the answer in duplicate provides an alternative just for the deprecated getSelectItems() method but it doesn't provides an alternative for the deprecated `selectItems` field and `setSelectItems()` method.

Is that something you can provide your inputs on?